# how to convert a data type avoiding System.FormatException?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to receive a string an convert it in integer, the code is this:

```
        int menu = 3
        int orden = 0;
        string query = @"select max(oppord)+1 as orden
                         from rhlibry.vaoppfi
                         where pincor = " + menu;
        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=RHLIBRY;uid=PC00;pwd=PC00;");
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, cn);
        cn.Open();
        OdbcDataReader oa = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (oa.Read())
        {
            orden = Int32.Parse(oa["orden"].ToString());
        }
        return orden;
```

the sql query return "orden" in string format, and I need transform it to integer.

The line `orden = Int32.Parse(oa["orden"].ToString());` returns a error of type System.FormatException.

Why? I do wrong?

Help me please !

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `oppord`?

Comment: stephen, the data type is numeric(8,0) in the DB

Comment: Do you have any records in that table? This may be because oa["orden"] is `DBNull.Value`

Comment: @DiegoFlores I think this is because your query result in a null return value.

Comment: Reza, how to solve this in the code?

Comment: I'll post an answer for you

Comment: Thanks Reza, I am new at this, and appreciate your help

Comment: @DiegoFlores Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Comment: @DiegoFlores By the way, here in StackOverflow when you find an answer helpful, you can kindly click on check mark near the answer to make it accepted. This way it will be more useful for future readers :)

Comment: @DiegoFlores You should know you can accept only one answer, but you can vote up as many answer as you find helpful by click on up arrow, including accepted one. You can also vote up for good questions :)

Comment: Thanks Reza,I did not have enough punctuation but now if. hahah! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because your query returns null value.

Suppose you have a Category table that have an Id column with values 1,2,3.
If you run this query:

```
SELECT Max(Id)+1 As Id From Category WHERE Id = -1
```

You will receive this result:

```
Id
----------
NULL
```

So when you use `Int32.Parse(oa["Id"].ToString())` you will receive a FormatException.

As a fix you can use:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Max(Id),0)+1 As Id From Category WHERE Id = -1
```

Also if your business logic allows, you can remove criteria.

Also in C# side, you can use int.TryParse():

```
int id = 0;
var idObject= oa["Id"];
if (idObject!=null)
   int.TryParse(oa["Id"].ToString(), out id);
```

Comment: `TryParse` was my first thought--fantastic